# IPCC 6 - What's the background of possible marine species loss?

Tags: climate-change, oceanography

The Figure "[Projected risks and impacts of climate change on natural and human systems at different global warming levels](https://www.ipcc.ch/report/ar6/syr/figures/summary-for-policymakers/figure-spm-3)" has this to say on species loss (only part of the image):
[image]

I can't quite make it out for the 2°C scenario, but for 3°C upward huge swathes of the pacific ocean are shown to lose 100% of the species to be "exposed to potentially dangerous temperature conditions."

My questions are:

- Does this purely look at temperature changes, or also CO2 uptake and ocean acidification?
- What physical change of ocean temperature does this represent?
- Over what timescale?

Comment: I think, you will probably have to wait for the final report to be available for a definite answer. You will probably find qualitative answers by skimming through the [report on Impacts, Adaptation and Vulnerability's](https://www.ipcc.ch/report/sixth-assessment-report-working-group-ii/) chapter about [Oceans and Coastal Ecosystems and Their Services](https://www.ipcc.ch/report/ar6/wg2/downloads/report/IPCC_AR6_WGII_Chapter03.pdf).

Comment: it is important to know that the temperature will increase the least at equator and increase the most closer to the poles,the picture in your question can be misunderstood as showing larger changes at equator.